# does Chrome in Ubuntu have "Recent Tabs"?

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome

Ubuntu 12, Chrome 30

As noted [here](http://lifehacker.com/reopen-closed-tabs-in-chrome-via-the-menu-1384943223), Chrome has a Recent Tabs feature. But in Ubuntu I don't see that option. Do I need to turn it on or is it just not available? When I search in settings there's no results for "recent".

Comment: Do you mean recently closed? I see this at the bottom of my New Tab page!

Comment: Yes it would be. Although you can always open recently closed tabs by pressing **shift** + **ctrl** + **T**. Try continue pressing it..

Comment: Shift-Ctrl-T did it... now why the heck is it not on the Chrome 3-bar menu like it is in Windows?

Comment: Many of the so-called tech sites (or their authors) don't seem to bother about the Linux desktop at all. Google takes care to mention whether a feature is truly cross-platform or limited. It's better to look at sites like http://chrome.blogspot.com or http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com for official information.

Comment: what the heck downvoter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, no.

The update your article refers to is about the Windows version of Chrome, and the Linux version didn't get this. We still have the 'Recently Closed' menu on the New Tab page. Personally, I prefer it, but you might want to hunt around `chrome://flags` and see if you can find a setting.

As [Saurav Kumar](https://askubuntu.com/users/124963/saurav-kumar) noted, pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> will bring back the recently closed tabs with the most recently closed tab first, which is very similar to the Recent Tabs menu item.

Comment: can I make an edit?

Comment: Make an edit to what?

Comment: I suggest you remove the "but you might want to ... if I helped." part. The first, because you could do that yourself and make it part of your answer and the second because it isn't required.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is dependent on the "Instant Extended API" feature of Google Chrome which is *not* available on Linux yet.

The addition of the "Recent Tabs" menu entry was (I believe) to compensate for the loss of the "Recently Closed" entry in the old New Tab page which Linux still has, so, no "Recent Tabs" menu entry.

Note: If you want the old New Tab page back *on Windows* (and the Recently Closed entry gone), disable "Instant Extended API" from here:
`chrome://flags/#enable-instant-extended-api`